# Unable to display Bitmap and text on a CMfcButton : Only picture displayed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc, bitmap

I would like to be able to display a bitmap and a text on a CMFC Button.

I succeed to display the bitmap, but, if i tried to display the text, the text don't display .

**Here is my code ( in my OnInitDialog) :**

```
    CPngImage image_;
    image_.Load(IDB_PNG2, AfxGetInstanceHandle());
    CBitmap bitmap_;
    bitmap_.Attach(image_.Detach());
    m_pButtonExport->SetBitmap(bitmap_);
    m_pButtonExport->SetWindowTextW(L"Text");
    m_pButtonExport->Invalidate();
```

Anyone have some ideas please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just a wild guess, have you tried calling [`CMFCButton::SizeToContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982726.aspx)?

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni It's not standard UI practice to use **both** an image and text on a graphic button.  Is your image good enough to indicate what the button does?  What about using a tool tip for the text instead?

Comment: Probleme solved. I modify my CMCbutton variable ( CMFCButton * to CMFCButton ) and added the DDX Function. All is ok now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Probleme solved. I modify my CMCbutton variable ( CMFCButton * to CMFCButton ) and added the DDX Function. All is ok now! Thanks :)

Comment: Please accept your own answer. I regret loosing my time just now coming inside this page to do nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use as below. Hope it will work.

```
demoBtn->m_bTopImage = TRUE;
```